# Finding the difference between two times in lubridate hms format in R

Tags: r, time, difference, lubridate

I have a row of times in hms format (from lubridate). 
For example,

```
begin = "12H 18M 48.58S" 
ending = "12H 21M 1.4S"
```

If I do 
ending - begin, it returns:

```
"3M -47.18S"
```

While this is correct, I would prefer the answer in seconds, so that I can use this value later as a numeric (to add to other values in the column I am hoping to build), and use in figures.

I want to find the time, in seconds, between these two times. I have tried, 
`as.duration(ending - start)`, and the following error comes up:

```
Error in sprintf("%ds (~%s %ss)", x, x2, unit, "s)") : 
  invalid format '%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: See `?period_to_seconds`.

Comment: that is it! Thank you!